# DHTMLX - ReferenceError: dhtmlXCellObject is not defined

Tags: dhtmlx

While upgrading dhtmlx to 4.1.3 pro, I am getting following error while loading dhtmlx js file in my document:

> ReferenceError: dhtmlXCellObject is not defined in dhtmlxtabbar.js(line 1204)

Please do help if any one have got the same.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're using tabbar source in your code and forgot to include sources\dhtmlxCommon\codebase\dhtmlxcontainer.js before it.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to load dhtmlxcontainer.js after tabbar. Now it is working if load before.